# Using System.Data.Linq in a Razor view

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I may have a fundamental misunderstanding of what is going on here, but I'm having an issue looping through a LinqToSQL class in my razor view:

```
<h3>Owners</h3>
@foreach (var ThisOwner in Prop.PropertyOwnerships.Where(p=p.bIsOwner.Value==true))
{
<div class="ODEditEntry">
...
```

I'm getting the following error:

Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

I tried putting @using System.Data.Linq at the top of the cshtml file but it is telling me that Linq doesn't exist in the System.Data namespace.  This is obviously not true and, yes, I do have system.data.linq as a reference in my project.

Any Ideas here?  Is a import needed?  Can I just not do Linq style stuff in my razor views?  That would seem....odd?

Comment: Can you use Linq in your normal classes? (just to be sure). The @Using statement should be enough.

Comment: Are you running this locally or is it deployed to another server?

Comment: Are you getting that error as well when setting the "Copy Local" property for the System.Data.Linq reference to true?

Comment: Works:  in my controller just fine.  In fact my current work around is this:ViewBag.OwnerList = Prop.PropertyOwnerships.Where(p => p.bIsOwner.Value == true).ToList();

Comment: This seems...odd.  Shouldn't System.Data.Linq be in the GAC and have universal access.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to import the namespace into your view by adding `@using System.Data.Linq` at the top of your view. However if you want it in all your views then you need to add `<add namespace="System.Data.Linq" />` to the web.config in your Views folder:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Data.Linq" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Although not relevent to your question you should really try to move this logic out of the view and into the controller, it will make things much easier to debug and means that your presentation is separated from your business logic.

Comment: are you saying in the last sentence there that the Linq should be pulled back into the controller and instead have the controller send the collection that has already been filtered?  Just trying to get a handle on the best way to handle things like this in my own code.

Comment: Yes, the view should only be concerned with the presentation of the data and leave the logic, sorting, ordering etc to the controller.

Comment: If the above doesn't work (adding to web.config in your views folder), you should also try to add the following to the main web.config file:

`<add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />`

in system.web\compilation\assemblies

Comment: TO elaborate on jao's answer, here's how you enter it into the web.config: 

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

Comment: @AdamFlanagan I get your point about pulling selection into the controller, but is sorting / ordering not more a point of presentation than logic? (Just curious to understand different perspectives...)

Comment: The section @jao mentions is already in the web.config under the views folder by default.

Answer (score 22):

What fixed it for me was to right click the System.Data.Linq assembly reference, then hit properties. In there set Copy Local to true.

Comment: YES!! it's work. maybe the view.cshtml is complied to a dll, but the dll doesn't reference the system.data.linq. why copy the system.data.linq to local is OK?

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours and hours googling and no solution worked but this is what helped...

**Remove everything inside `<assemblies>` element in web.config!**

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.7.2">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <!-- etc etc blah blah -->
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Either add `System.Core` in there, or even better, remove everything and change it to:

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
```

**Explanation**

The System.Linq namespace is defined in System.Core, right? So we either need to add it to the `<assemblies>` list , or (because System.Core *is always referenced in your root web.config* located at "%Windir%/Microsoft.NET/v4.0.30319/Framework/whatever") remove everything from `<assemblies>` to prevent conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Linq-to-Sql datacontext exist outside of the web project (e.g. in another class library)? If so, where you have added a reference to that project it all builds fine, but in the Razor view you are trying to directly access a type from the `System.Data.Linq` assembly without referencing it in the web project. Try adding the reference to the main web project and see what you get.

Comment: It is all in the same project

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to `System.Data.Linq` in your project and/or in your `Web.config`.

Comment: I have it in references.  I'll try adding it to the assemblies section of web.config.