# System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection does not contain a definition for 'Single'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Some background info, I'm using MVC3 w/ EF & db first method, along with Razor templating. I'm passing in a view model to a view, that view model has a couple different collections of obj, i'm using one of them to populate a webgrid (wgSettings) as its source parameter. Below is the code in which i'm trying to get some detailed information about a related row.
Details:
MyInfo is the Dictionary from the viewmodel, 
item is the anonymous row object that the webgrid uses to populate the row
item.Value.Value is the value of the id field of the object from the dictionary that I want to grab
MySettings is a System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection, therefore, I can use extension methods like Single(), FirstOrDefault(), etc.

using quick watch I am able to navigate the object and see the values I would expect, however when debugging, and accessing the view @ runtime, I am getting the following error.

On line:
"@Model.MyInfo[Guid.Parse(item.Value.Value)].MySettings.Single().Value"
debugger is saying 
'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Single' but when I quickwatch it i am getting value.

Below is the code.

```
wgSettings.Column(header: "Value", columnName:"Value", canSort:true, format:  
        @<text>
        @if (item.Value.Type == "Guid" && item.Value.Value != null) {             

            @Model.MyInfo[Guid.Parse(item.Value.Value)].MySettings.Single().Value
        }
        else if (item.Value.Type == "Boolean") { 
            @item.Value.Value 
        }
        else {
            @item.Value.Value 
        }

        </text>
```

Answer (score 2):

The Linq extension methods are not in scope, you need to add this to the top (or you can add to web.config)

```
@using System.Linq;
```

Or in the web.config in the views folder:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Linq" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

See this question for a similar problem for a different namespace:

[Using System.Data.Linq in a Razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896842/using-system-data-linq-in-a-razor-view)

Comment: :-\ same error ... i tried both and even combined ways but still throwing the same error ... but i something interesting happened to make me think it's not a namespace issue ... i replaced

Comment: something interesting happened to make me think it's not a namespace issue ... i replaced
@Model.MyInfo[Guid.Parse(item.Value.Value)].MySettings.Single().Value with 
@Model.MyInfo[Guid.Parse("1234568-abc3-1234-1234-123456789abc")].MySettings.Single().Value
and I got my result, this leads me to believe the item object from the row is not being properly parsed ... causing the corresponding object to not get intialized to an EntityCollectionObject ...

Comment: kinda fixed it, what I wound up doing was grabbing the guid into a string a couple lines above where I needed to use it:
@{ string itemGuid = item.Value.Value;}

then @Model.MyInfo[Guid.Parse(itemGuid)].MySettings.Single().Value
gave me my value with no error ...