# How do I use LINQ in an ASP.NET Razor MVC4 view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an ASP.NET Razor MVC4 view with the following `@using` statement at the top to include `LINQ` in the page.

```
@using System.Linq
```

Then I have a loop where I want to access specific elements of the contents of a `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary object (@Model.content)`. In this case,

element 1->last.

```
    @for (int i = 1; i < @Model.content.Count; i++)
    {
        <li class="bullet">
          @Model.content.ElementAt(i)
        </li>
    }
```

I am receiving the following error.

> 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' does not
>   contain a definition for 'ElementAt'

What do I need to do to utilize LINQ in this Razor view?

I know I could use a `foreach` to iterate all the elements, but in this situation need to access specific elements.

Comment: This one is for MVC3, but it's probably still relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896842/using-system-data-linq-in-a-razor-view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make System.Linq work for your purpose, but I would strongly suggest against it.

You'll wind up iterating your collection multiple times over using `ElementAt`. As your collection grows, performance will be terrible.

You'd be far better off using a foreach loop and tracking the index yourself (please excuse the razor syntax if it's a bit off):

```
@{ var counter = 0; }

@foreach(var kvp in @Model.content)
{
    @if(counter > 0){
        <li class="bullet">
            @kvp.Value
        </li>
    }
    @{ counter++; }
}
```