# How to filter children object using WHERE statement in lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

here is the scenario:
- I have a list of products.
- each product has a number of parts.
- The parts has two types: MAIN and OPTIONAL.

I want to bring the list of the main parts of a product. What would be the statement?

I am currently using this statement but returns an error:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Products.FirstOrDefault().Parts.Where(i => i.PartType == percobaan2.Models.PartType.Main))
```

Thanks for you help

UPDATE:

here is the error:

*An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.*

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

this code works though. But I need to add the where filter:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Products.FirstOrDefault().Parts)
```

UPDATED 2:

Here is my viewmodel class updated with mainparts property:

```
public class ProductDetail
    {
        public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Part> Parts { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<percobaan2.Models.Version> Versions { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Producer> Producers { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Part> MainParts
        {
            get
            {
                return Parts.Where(p => p.PartType == PartType.Main);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Somewhat hard to answer without knowing how your types are defined. If you can provide those (at least the parts you're trying to query at the moment), that would be helpful.

Comment: Have you referenced System.Data.Linq? As in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896842/using-system-data-linq-in-a-razor-view).

Comment: @TiesonT. I added an Additional information, I think it might help. The problem is only in the WHERE extenstion :(

Comment: @Nashibukasan I updated the question. It shows a working linq statement, but without WHERE clause. But when I add WHERE it gives an error

Comment: Perhaps post what happens if you perform the same action on the same data inside a controller? Might need more info around 'percobaan2' as well. Not sure I can help at this point sorry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DisplayFor` can't be called on an `IEnumerable` like that. It needs to be a direct property of a model.

`@Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Products.FirstOrDefault().Parts)` works because `Parts` is a property that exists on your `Product` type.

If you need to be able to filter the parts but still want the HTML helper, define another property like so:

```
public class Product
{
    public IEnumerable<Part> MainParts
    {
        get
        {
            return Parts.Where(i => i.PartType == PartType.Main);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use

`@Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Products.FirstOrDefault().MainParts)`

If you're using an EF-generated class, just make this a partial class and use it as-is.

Comment: Thanks sir! although I am having one stupid question still (I am learning and eager to learn more. Where should I put that property class? shall I make another class file somewhere in the solution?

Comment: Depends. Either edit the original class to include whatever new properties you need, or add a new class file. I usually create a `Components` folder and drop my utility classes and whatnot in there. If I have more than a few I create subfolders and organize them as seems appropriate.

Comment: Alright, I think I found it. Actually I am using a viewModel for the view above, and it seems a perfect place for the property class. But, the @Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Products.FirstOrDefault().MainParts) does not work. Please have a look on my updated question.

Comment: "Does not work" means what? Same error as before, or not the output you were expecting? Did you rebuild the project?

Comment: "does not work" means the "MainParts" on @Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Products.FirstOrDefault().MainParts) is not recognized by the Razor. I tried ro rebuild the solution but still. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Close the razor file and then re-open it.

Comment: I realized this: when the MainParts property in the viewmodel, the razor view can work with this ONLY: @Html.DisplayFor(p => p.MainParts). It means I cannot make a statement like: @Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Products.FirstOrDefault().MainParts). And when I debug the application using the @Html.DisplayFor(p => p.MainParts), it says null reference which is obvious because I need to pass the product in which we are trying to get its main parts. I am losing myself now. Please help :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55029/discussion-between-tieson-t-and-ace-supriatna).

Comment: actually I am not using EF generated view, I am using DisplayTemplates. If it is too complicated I will try the partial view, even though I would prefer the DisplayTemplates because the rest of my application using DisplayTemplates and EditorTemplates. Just makes it neat.