# I'm getting an error. The "Where" and "Take" values do not appear in the list data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I haven't opened the project in a long time.

There were errors in references when I opened.

I fixed the references.

I made Nuget updates.

I am getting error on cshtml pages.

In the list data, values such as "where", "take", "skip" do not appear.

No problem with .cs pages.
I just have problems with .cshtml pages.

Project 3 layers.

1st layer: Web Site

2nd layer: Database operations

Layer 3: communicates between the web and layer 2

Could there be a problem with updated references?

**TR:::**

Merhaba,

Projeyi uzun zamandır açmamıştım.

Açtığımda referanslarda hatalar vardı.

Referansları düzelttim.

Nuget güncellemelerini yaptım.

cshtml sayfalarında hata alıyorum.

Liste verisinde "where", "take", "skip" gibi değerler görünmüyor.

.cs sayfalarında sorun yok.

Sadece .cshtml sayfalarında sorun var.

Proje 3 katmanlı.

1. katman: Web Site
2. katman: Veritabanı işlemleri
3. katman: 2. katman ile web site arası iletişim kurar

Güncellenen referanslar ile ilgili bir sorun olabilir mi?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKvjl.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kxLv.jpg)

Comment: There is probably a @using System.Linq missing

Comment: doesn't look that simple :( I tried.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Errors;
 https://i.imgur.com/TczfPls.jpg , https://i.imgur.com/TddPPnu.jpg , https://i.imgur.com/EwzmuWk.jpg

Comment: None of these images show your imports/usings. Have you referenced System.Data.Linq.dll? See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/5896842 and the several answers there.

Comment: Unfortunately. It didn't work. I even upgraded the .Net Framework version.